# How do I regain DDMS access to Galaxy Tab's /data partition?

Tags: android, ddms

Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 16BG Wifi-only, retail (not I/O) edition, running 3.1.

Up until a few days ago, I could access /data/data/com.my.app/{databases,...} from the Eclipse DDMS perspective without issues.  This helped with development by e.g. letting me pull sqlite files to make sure my DB code was doing what I thought it should be doing, accessing the sqlite files from the Linux command line.

A few days ago I came to my desk and found the tab in a strange state:  as if stuck in the boot process, and warm to the touch, suggesting that the CPU was spinning.

I assumed it was a crash, rebooted it and thought nothing more of it until, earlier today, I can no longer get DDMS access to /data.  /system and /mnt are accessible.

Is anyone aware of what might have caused that change, and if/how it can be reversed?  I had not rooted the tab before, and although I understand rooting it may bring back access to /data (over DDMS?) I'd rather try to understand what happened before proceeding.

Has anyone else seen the same/similar behavior?

Update:  Here's what this looks like from an ADB shell:

> shell@android:/ $ ls -ld data
>   drwxrwx--x system   system            2011-07-05 15:49 data
>   shell@android:/ $ cd data
>   shell@android:/data $ ls
>   opendir failed, Permission denied
>   255|shell@android:/data $

Comment: What you experienced before must have been a bug or something, as `/data` is supposed to be inaccessible on production devices.

Comment: Agree with CommonsWare although i once had the same experience with my ADP1 on Android 1.5